# Do network switches "short-circuit" traffic?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, nas, switch

I plan to buy a network switch for home use since my router has no ethernet ports unused and I'm considering a switch on Amazon, like a [TP-Link SG108](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00A121WN6) (but haven't decided on a specific one), and I'd like to know if network switches can handle higher bandwidth *between* devices connected to it.

I have a setup like this:

> Modem -> Router -> (NAS, server, desktop, laptop, etc)

The switch will be added after the router, the NAS and server will be connected to the switch, and some WiFi devices will connect to the router directly.

So far, all devices are connected via 1Gbps ethernet; however, I would like to allow *certain devices* to transfer data at up to 2Gbps (the home server and NAS both have multiple ethernet ports and I plan to use channel bonding), but since the router and switch will only be connected via a single 1Gbps link, the router would act as a bottleneck if all traffic needed to go through it.

1. Will the network switch know to "short-circuit" the connections in this case?
2. Does it depend on the switch itself?
3. Will performing 1Gbps+ transfers between two devices downstream from the switch saturate the upstream connection to the router, causing latency issues between other devices that connect from the switch to WAN?

Comment: Thanks, your comment was useful in addition to @Tom Yan's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traffics will only go to the router (or the switch it embeds) if their destinations are hosts connected to it (either the WAN side or the LAN side). You can try connect only the hosts to the switch but not the router, they will still be able to communicate with each other (as long as you configure IP/route properly on them manually; as you probably rely on the DHCP server on the router)

Answer (score 0):

You should connect all device to the switch, and not mix between router and switch. That way, all devices get the best LAN bandwidth without needing to share the router-switch connection. The latter is then only used for Internet uplink.

For channel bonding a managed switch might be required - depending on the exact mode. Most likely, bonded channels will only provide more than 1G in total, ie. when multiple clients are connecting.